# Customizing interface of multiselect in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, multiselect

My  multi select list is very large, it is difficult to find out which options are selected, I want to change it into some thing like following, is it possible?
It can be any where, but currently I have a custom "customer_address" attribute type "multiselect",
[image]

I am creating my attribute like this my sql script,

```
    <?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'additional_managers', array(
    'label' => 'Additional Store/Site Managers',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'multiselect',
    'source' => 'abc_districtmanager/address_attribute_source_districtmanager',
    'onclick' => 'getSelectValues(this)',
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'position' => 100
));

$used_in_forms = array(
     'adminhtml_customer_address',
     'customer_address_edit',
     'customer_register_address'
    );

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer_address', 'additional_managers');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $used_in_forms); 
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Not enough context. Where is this? Custom code?

Comment: @ ProxiBlue  update the question, as said it can be any where

Comment: This is related to html multi select usability in general. Take a look into: http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/ specifically the example: ASMSELECT. After that you can think on integrating some solution into Magento adminhtml. Another solution I just googled: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: you want to select item in my item?

Comment: my selected items should appear in my item

Comment: can you paste the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my purpose with a slight changed interface by using "Chosen" jquery.

Download **Chosen Jquery** [chosen.jquery.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js) and [chosen.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css), place these files in your design, Add them to you module in respected .xml file, in head like

```
     <reference name="head">
        <!--            Adding js and css to use "chosen" instead of "select" for "multiselect" input types-->
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/chosen.jquery.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/chosen.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

be careful about **path of files**, after this, in your respected view (**.phtml**) use Chosen

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".myClass").chosen();
});
```

This will change interface of elements having class "myClass", output might like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this functionality by below code

```
<select onchange="getSelectValues(this)"></select>



    function getSelectValues(select) {

          var options = select && select.options;
          var opt;

          for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
            opt = options[i];

            if (opt.selected) {
               opttext +=opt.text+'<br />';
            }
          }
          document.getElementById('showdiv').innerHtml=opttext;
        }
```

doing with prototype

```
$("_itemNaNadditional_managers").invoke('observe', 'change', function() {

    var options = $("_itemNaNadditional_managers").options;
              var opt;

              for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
                opt = options[i];

                if (opt.selected) {
                   opttext +=opt.text+'<br />';
                }
              }
              document.getElementById('showdiv').innerHtml=opttext;

});
```

Comment: I am creating an attribute of type "multiselect",its source model is "abc_districtmanager/address_attribute_source_districtmanager", from where it is being populated, and being used in "$used_in_forms = array(
     'adminhtml_customer_address',
     'customer_address_edit',
     'customer_register_address'
    );"

Comment: you can add js function in form field `'onchange' => 'getSelectValues(this)',`

Comment: this your form  field? then add it there..

Comment: bro it is multiselect, how "onchange" will work

Comment: the function is working for multiselect.  try onchange or onclick it will work

Comment: Tried both "onchange or onclick", it never calls "getSelectValues(this)"

Comment: What is this statement doing "<select onchange="getSelectValues(this)"></select>"

Comment: i added the sample code bro because you question was not clear what you want at first time.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I have add you snippet in my file "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/abc/addressmanager/address.phtml", which being used to create form,it never comes in you function

Comment: no this will not work can you paste the field id?

Comment: field id:- "_itemNaNadditional_managers"

Comment: add this in your phtml file and make sure the id is correct

Comment: by adding this, my form disappeared,other than this (above solution in my question), can you suggest an other solution to show selected options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38225/discussion-between-abdul-ghaffar-and-qaisar-satti).