# How to use Chosen in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, jquery, multiselect-attribute, select

I need to use **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** in magento instead of "select " for multi select.I didn't find any thing about it. How should I add jquery for it. I am trying to solve [Following](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110089/customizing-interface-of-multiselect-in-magento/110103?noredirect=1#comment149650_110103) issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download **Chosen Jquery** files[chosen.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css) and [chosen.jquery.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js) , place these files in your design, , Add them to you module in respected .xml file, in head like

```
<reference name="head">
    <!--            Adding js and css to use "chosen" instead of "select" for "multiselect" input types-->
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/chosen.jquery.js</name>
    </action>
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/chosen.css</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

be careful about **path of files**, after this, in your respected view (**.phtm**l) use Chosen

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".myClass").chosen();
});
```

This will change interface of elements having class "myClass", output might like this 
[image]